# Difference between German prepositions an and auf

Tags: word-choice, preposition

Ich führe **an** or **auf** der Bühne auf.
Which preposition is correct here?

Comment: What do you think is correct? Why do you think so? Why do you think only one of them is correct? Why not a third preposition? In which context do you want to use this sentence? I voted -1 because this question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on whether the action happens *at the stage* or *on stage*.

> Das Stück wird an der Schaubühne aufgeführt.

This means that the play is performed at the Schaubühne (that's a theatre in Berlin).

> Das Stück wird auf der Bühne aufgeführt.

While this means it's performed on stage rather than right between the audience.

> Das Stück wird an der Bühne aufgeführt.

And this means it's performed next to the stage rather than on it.